# How do I generate line item numbers in an oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

This seems like it should be a classic invoice-item problem that has already been solved but maybe I'm not using the right words in my searches.

I am running a query like this (this is just a simple example, my real query is much more complex but it returns the same results):

```
select invoice.inv_num, item.name, item.qty 
 from invoice invoice, item 
 where invoice.inv_num = item.inv_num
 order by invoice.inv_num
```

I need to generate an item number column that increments for each item but starts over at 1 for each new invoice number.  So, for example, I need the end result to look something like this:

```
inv_num   item_num   name            qty
-------   --------   -------------   ---
111       1          red widgets     10
111       2          blue widgets    5
222       1          green_widgets   7
222       2          red_widgets     16
222       3          black_widgets   10
333       1          blue_widgets    8
333       2          red_widgets     12
```

We are still using Oracle 9i in case that makes a difference.

Comment: CONNECT BY, then you can use the LEVEL pseudocolumn

Comment: @Randy I've never even heard of CONNECT BY and LEVEL so I could be misunderstanding, but I just did a quick google search and it looks like the LEVEL would give me a depth (if I had items under other items) and not a counter.

Comment: you are correct - i misread, level is only one deep each time, not a counter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the oracle rank or row_number analytic functions (depending on how you want to deal with duplicates/euqally ranked items).

Here's how you would add a 4th column item_number to your query :

```
select invoice.inv_num, item.name, item.qty ,
       row_number() over (partition by inv_num order by qty desc) item_num
 from invoice invoice, item 
 where invoice.inv_num = item.inv_num
 order by invoice.inv_num
```

- The counter resets at each new invoice number becuase of the
  partition by clause.
- Within an invoice, the rank/item number is    decided by qty (highest
  to lowest).
- In the above query, rank or row_number will give the same result with your data. But if there are multiple items with the same quantity in an invoice (10 red, 10 blue widgets), rank will give you equal item numbers, so in this case row_number is appropriate.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407

Answer (score 3):

```
select invoice.inv_num,
       item.name,
       item.qty,
       row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY invoice.inv_num order by item.qty desc) as item_num
 from invoice invoice, item 
 where invoice.inv_num = item.inv_num
 order by invoice.inv_num
```

`row_number()` generates Number starting with 1.. And we restart the sequence for every *INV_NUM* using `PARTITION BY` clause. And ordering of numbering with qty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the item name of an invoice is unique you can use rank() aggregate function:

```
create table TESTTABLE(inv_num NUMBER,iname VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),qty NUMBER);

insert into TESTTABLE values(111,'red widgets',10);
insert into TESTTABLE values(111,'blue widgets',5);
insert into TESTTABLE values(222,'green_widgets',7);
insert into TESTTABLE values(222,'red_widgets',16);
insert into TESTTABLE values(222,'black_widgets',10);
insert into TESTTABLE values(333,'blue_widgets',8);
insert into TESTTABLE values(333,'red_widgets',12);
commit;

select inv_num, iname, qty ,
 rank() over (PARTITION BY inv_num ORDER BY iname) as item_num
 from TESTTABLE
 order by inv_num;
```